# Problema al subir un proyecto a GitHub

Tags: github

Subí un app de escritorio a GitHub. Y al descargarla para abrirla en la pc la baja pero sin las clases. El package esta vació y si quiero ejecutar me dice que no encuentra la clase Main.
En el git la carpeta src me aparece con una flechita blanca. Lo cual nunca me paso con los otros proyectos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en la carpeta build me figuran todas las clases. Pero aparecen como 4 veces cada una

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!